# Login Failed for user 'NT Authority\Anonymous Logon' with identity_impersonate = true

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, web-config

My application is hosted on IIS, where app pool is running with Built-in Account Network Service and Asp.Net impersonation is true for this website.

Website connects to sql server with Integrated Security = True

And all the required roles are provided in Web.config Allowed Roles.

Comment: Since you enabled impersonation, user credentials from the browser side should be used by IIS/ASP.NET to connect to SQL Server. However, if your domain administrators didn't configure delegation properly, IIS/ASP.NET won't be able to pass the credentials on. That's why you saw the error message and only your domain administrators can help resolve it.

Comment: Possible problem: quote from the Microsoft documentation on impersonation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/134ec8tc(v=vs.100)): "_Impersonation is independent of the authentication mode configured using the authentication configuration element. The authentication element is used to determine the User property of the current HttpContext. Impersonation is used to determine the WindowsIdentity of the ASP.NET application._"  So make sure the user that gets to the SQL Server comes from WindowsIdentity not from the HttpContext.

Comment: This is a sql exception, the application pool identity needs an account that can access the database. By changing the application pool identity to use a specific service account, and granting this service account permissions to SQL Server.